# addHeader() and setHeader() not working

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am preparing for OCPJWCD. I am a little stuck on addHeader and setHeader methods. I do 
understand the difference, but when i am trying to implement it in the code and retrieving
the values either via getHeaders() or getHeader(). It is showing value as null. I am adding
the code here. Can someone check and let me know, what exactly is going wrong.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Ben
 * Date: 7/14/13
 * Time: 1:51 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class TestHeaderServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
  }


  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("ben","value1");
    /*httpServletResponse.addHeader("ben","value1");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("ben","value2");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("ben","value3");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("ben","value4");*/
    String value = httpServletRequest.getHeader("ben");
    out.println("value is: " + value)    ;
   /* Enumeration<String> enumeration = httpServletRequest.getHeaders("ben");
    while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
      System.out.println("It has elements");

    }*/


  }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the header to the `response`, and trying to fetch that from the `request` object in the same *HTTP Request-Response* cycle. It won't work , because the initial `request` which invoked this Servlet didn't had this header. It gets added to the `response` and sent back to the client , you cannot retrieve it back from the `request` object . If you need to set something in the `response` and retrieve it back from the `request` object then you can use [Cookie](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html).

Comment: Huh? Since when does a client/webbrowser automagically copy and set a response header as a header of the subsequent request?

Comment: You already answered that part. You're only adding a wrong assumption thereafter.

Comment: An alternative is sending a redirect with a query parameter (or just using the HTTP session; it's also backed by a cookie).

Comment: @TheNewIdiot i understood that in the same request and response cycle we cannot retrieve the Header. What i didn't was the last part. That i can use a Cookie from the request object. I want to retrieve the header, can i update the code to have a sendRedirect() and use request object to retrieve the header. I am a little confused, can you brief your last part more?